# HTML form submits empty variables on mobile phones but works fine on pc browsers

Tags: php, html, forms, mobile, submit

I am quite a rookie when it comes to website design, but I managed to set up a website with bootstrap and jquery including a small form (inside a modal) for guests to register to an event.

The form sends its data (attending, name, etc) to a php script which then sends it to mail and echos the mailbody which is then also displayed in an iFrame for the user to see the confirmation.

Everything works fine on PC. I have tested it on three different machines with chrome, firefox and IE.

It works equally well on my personal Android phone.

Here is the catch: On my company Blackberry and on my sister's Android it does not work. The form seems to work and triggers the PHP but it seems to pass only empty variables. The generated mail and the confirmation in the iFrame is blank.

Any ideas what is wrong? Security settings or anything that prevents actual data to be send? I am puzzled and googled this for an hour without finding a solution...

The code (shortened):

```
<form action="rueckmeldung.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" target="hiddenForm" onsubmit="this.reset();" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > <!-- onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false; window.location.assign('#close')"-->

    <IFRAME style="display:none; width:100%; height:auto; border:0; margin-left: 5rem; margin-right: 5rem;" name="hiddenForm" id="hiddenframeID" class="mdlRMhide2"></IFRAME>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body mdlRMhide1" novalidate="novalidate">
            <!-- Ja/Nein-->
            <section id="secJaNein" class="modal-section">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="input-wrap"><input type="radio" name="entrykommejanein" id="e1" value="Ja" required />
                        <label for="e1"><h3>Natürlich komme ich!</h3></label></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="input-wrap"><input type="radio" name="entrykommejanein" id="e2" value="Nein" required />
                        <label for="e2"><h3>Leider schaffe ich es nicht</h3></label></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- Name Gast -->
            <section id="secGast" class="modal-section">
                <div class= "row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="gastVorname"><h2>Vorname</h2></label>
                            <input type="text" name="entryvorname" id="gastVorname"  class="form-control" required >
                            <!-- <small class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty" data-fv-for="guest-first-name" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">First name is required</small> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="gastNachname"><h2>Nachname</h2></label>
                            <input type="text" name="entrynachname" id="gastNachname"  class="form-control" required >
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

    </div>

    <!-- Modal Footer -->               
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 mdlRMhide1">
                <button class="button btn btn-lg form-btn" type="submit"  value="Submit" >Abschicken</button>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-12 mdlRMhide2" style="display:none">
                <button class="button btn btn-lg form-btn btnModalRMClose" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
            </div>                                      
        </div>              
    </div>                      

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$myemail = 'mail@domain.com';

$kommejanein = $_POST['entrykommejanein'];
$vorname = $_POST['entryvorname']; 
$nachname = $_POST['entrynachname']; 

$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Rückmeldung von $vorname $nachname : $kommejanein";
$email_body = "\n Teilnahme: $kommejanein \n Gast: $vorname $nachname";

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "From: $myemail";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: $myemail";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,implode("\r\n",$headers));

echo nl2br($email_body);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the opening form-tag is missing? Use `var_dump($_POST)` to check results on targeted page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The form tag is there but I messed up the format in my question. I just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found the problem, although I do not quite understand, why it caused trouble on one android but not on another and not on PC...

After taking out

```
onsubmit="this.reset();"
```

it worked on all devices (so far) and the formular content is forwarded to PHP.